# VB6/MS Access unusual behaviour with saved records

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 application and it links to a MS Access DB. All records on a data entry screen are written or read using ADO/SQL.

At one user site, (using Win 7 - his UAC was set to the maximum security so to start with, there were errors reading/writing galore! Furthermore the app and Data (sub-folder) folder was set to only read. So once I corrected all of this by changing Security for "All User" to FULL CONTROL, the records were written to the DB. However when I open the MDB from MS Access directly I was unable to see ANY records in any of the 3 tables where the Client entered data from the front end.

So 
1. either MS Access is hiding the rows in the table with data and display and blank table or 
2. there is a hidden copy of the MDB in the Data sub-folder (as the program check the availability of the MDB file when it starts and if unavailable it posts a Message Box error

Has anyone seen this behaviour and if it is #2, how do I in Win 7 show all files - bear in mind that MDBs are not operating system files so by default should not be hidden. OR is this some AV (Symantec) activity?

Please see this link from Y 2004 which is exactly like my issue - but there was no answer: 
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/hidden-records-t1086918.html

Appreciate any help anyone can shed

Regards
Fonz

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an improperly designed application that puts writable data (an MDB file here) within a protected folder ("Program Files") and is being run with no application manifest stating that it is "Vista aware."  If you do this Windows will try to fit a standard set of appcompat shims to the program, and in this case most likely the file virtualization shim is at work.

This results in each user creating private copies of the orginal data within their Virtual Store folder.  These private copies are what gets updated.

A proper manifest would result in a fatal runtime error on this security violation instead, making it quicker to understand what is being done wrong and generally leading to a faster resolution.

Things such as INI files, MDB files, and other application resources that must be updated and available to any user of the system should be put into an application-specific folder your installer creates under [CommonAppData].  You installer should set the desired security attributes on the subfolder to contain writable files so that all users have the desired access.  The default here is "owner" access which probably is not what you would want (file creator has full access, others have read access).

This works on any version of Windows including Windows 95 with the IE4 Desktop Update.  It is fairly easy to accomplish via Installer MSI packages.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% certain about which MDB file is being written to? If you are writing then seeing your records in the VB6 but then can't see them in the MDB that you open, it's possible that it's doing it to a different file.

I suggest you use process monitor to verify exactly which file is being written to by the VB6 app. That will allow you to troubleshoot further.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

It can be a little busy but it will let you establish exactly which file is being written to regardless of any asuumptions you make about the operation of your code.